# Notificación push

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, push-notification, activity

Si mi aplicación esta ejecutada en primer plano y recibo notificaciones, me manda a la actividad que yo especifique, pero si la app esta en segundo plano, se vuelve a abrir y muestra la actividad principal, como puedo hacer para que al recibir una notificaciones se abra la actividad que yo deseo, no mi actividad principal

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(MyfirebaseMessagingService.this, registro.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.putExtra("Mensaje", remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("Sección 15");
    notificationBuilder.setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    //notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0,notificationBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 1):

Gracias por agregar tu código, el `Intent` define que clase se abrira, en este caso se abre la clase `registro`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MyfirebaseMessagingService.this, registro.class);
```

Si deseas abrir otra clase debes especificarla en el `Intent`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MyfirebaseMessagingService.this, nuevaClase.class);
```

---

Otra opción es que al recibir tu clase en `onCreate()` el bundle, tenga una valor el cual determina abrir otra nueva `Actitivy` y cerrar la principal, ejemplo:

```
...
Intent intent = new Intent(MyfirebaseMessagingService.this, MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.putExtra("idScreen", 12);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
...
```

Al recibir el valor en la clase MainActivity determina abrir otra clase:

```
@Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {


      int idScreen = getIntent().getExtras().getString("idScreen");
      if(idScreen == 12){
        startActivity(new Intent(this, OtraActivity.class). // Abre nueva Activity.
        finish(); //Cierra Activity principal.
      }

        // clean intent for new Push Notification Data.
        super.onNewIntent(null);
    }
```

Comment: De la primer forma que comentas ya lo intente de echo la clase registro es a donde quiero que me mande la aplicación al abrir mi notificación, pero no funciona de echo se vuelve a abrir mi actividad principal y como que se encima, me explico: cuando abro mi aplicacion, la pongo en segundo plano y envio una notificacion y esta notificacion abre mi aplicacion es como si me estuviera abriendo dos veces la actividad, es como que se enciman

Comment: intente realizar esto pero sin exito Jorge

Comment: pasate por aca si podes https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/151752/notificacion-push-android-hacer-algo-cuando-llega-push-app-cerrada