# notificacion push android hacer algo cuando llega push app cerrada

Tags: java, android, firebase

Tengo en mi app configurado notificaciones push con firebase , hasta aca todo bien , recibo las notificaciones con la app prendida y apagada , cuando esta abierta y me llega algo pregunto por el cuerpo para hacer determinadas acciones por ejemplo abrir otra actividad  como el siguiente ejemplo

```
 public class MiFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    public static final String TAG = "NOTICIAS";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        String from = remoteMessage.getFrom();
        Log.d(TAG, "Mensaje recibido de: " + from);

        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Notificación: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

            mostrarNotificacion(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Data: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        }

    }

    private void mostrarNotificacion(String title, String body) {

        Intent intent = null;
        if(body.equals("Login")){
            intent = new Intent(this, Login.class);
        }
        if(body.equals("AppIntro")){
            intent = new Intent(this, AppIntroGalery.class);

        }
        if(body.equals("Menu")){
            intent = new Intent(this, TabsActivity.class);
        }

        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
                .setSound(soundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());

    } }
```

lo que si nose como se podria lograr es para cuando este cerrada este codigo parece no funcionar solamente la abre pero no va a las diferentes actividades alguna idea?

Intente meterle un flag al intent

```
intent = new Intent(this, SplashInicio.class);
    intent.putExtra("idScreen", 12);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

clase splash :

```
 @Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {


    String idScreen = getIntent().getExtras().getString("idScreen");
    if(idScreen.equals("12")){
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Login.class));

    }

    // clean intent for new Push Notification Data.
    super.onNewIntent(null);
}
```

tambien sin resultados , para ser mas especifico necesito que cuando este cerrada la app y me llege una notificaciones , depende de lo que me llege en el mensaje hacer una accion determinada lo mejor seria poder abrir una actividad y mandarle alguna bandera o no

Agrego Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

package="odontosys.com.odontosys">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REORDER_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/pagoexitosoxxxhdpi"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/audi"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <service

        android:name=".MiFirebaseInstanceIdService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </service>

    <service
        android:name=".MiFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

    <activity android:name=".SplashInicio"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Login"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <activity android:name=".ListadoClientes"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".AppIntroGalery"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
    </activity>


    <activity
        android:name=".TabsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_tabs"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

    </activity>


</application>
```

Comment: Una pregunta, ¿estas enviando las notificaciones desde la consola de firebase?

Comment: Exactamente @MiguelOsorio

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bruno, la recepción de datos en tu clase que extiende de `FirebaseMessagingService` y que específicamente ocurre en `onMessageReceived()` se entiende que es para generar una notificación, esto no importado si la aplicación esta abierta o cerrada.

En cuanto a tu método este puede funcionar sin ningún problema, NO necesitas especificar ningún tipo de FLAG o usar [onNewIntent()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)):

```
   private void mostrarNotificacion(String title, String body) {

        Intent intent = null;
        if(body.equals("Login")){
            intent = new Intent(this, Login.class);
        }
        if(body.equals("AppIntro")){
            intent = new Intent(this, AppIntroGalery.class);

        }
        if(body.equals("Menu")){
            intent = new Intent(this, TabsActivity.class);
        }

        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
                .setSound(soundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());

    }
```

Para que funcione correctamente tienes que tomar en cuenta estos puntos:

1) Necesitas especificar tus activities dentro de tu archivo AndroidManifest.xml

```
 ...  
        <activity android:name=".Login"/>
        <activity android:name=".AppIntroGalery"/>
        <activity android:name=".TabsActivity"/>
    </application>

...
```

2) El parámetro `body` debe contener específicamente el texto que indicas en la comparación:

```
   if(body.equals("Login")){
   ...
   if(body.equals("AppIntro")){
   ...
   if(body.equals("Menu")){
   ...
```

3) el punto mas importante es que usando FCM se recibe en [RemoteMessage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/RemoteMessage) y no un Bundle. Estas mostrando la notificación si `remoteMessage.getNotification()`:

```
   if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Notificación: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

            mostrarNotificacion(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }
```

pero no abre el `intent` hacia la Activity porque el valor de `remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody()` , no es "Login", "AppIntro" o "Menu", debes revisar este punto.

---

Es importante también cambiar el código de la notificación ya que si recibiste una anteriormente que no tenía `body` con el mismo código que tienes con valor 0, entonces esto provocaria que no abra ninguna Activity, te sugiero crear un método para obtener un valor aleatorio que servira como código:

```
private int getRandomCode(){
    //Obtiene un valor entre 1000.
    Random rand = new Random();
    return rand.nextInt(1000 - 0 + 1);
}
```

y definir este código en los intent:

```
 private void mostrarNotificacion(String title, String body) {

        int codigo = getRandomCode();

        Intent intent = null;
        if(body.equals("Login")){
            intent = new Intent(this, Login.class);
        }
        if(body.equals("AppIntro")){
            intent = new Intent(this, AppIntroGalery.class);

        }
        if(body.equals("Menu")){
            intent = new Intent(this, TabsActivity.class);
        }

       // intent = new Intent(this, TabsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("idScreen", 12);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, codigo/*0*/, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
                .setSound(soundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(codigo /*0*/, notificationBuilder.build());

 }
```

---

En este caso únicamente la primera notificación abrirá una `Activity` en la aplicación ya que como comentaba la condición es que `body` tenga un valor de "Login", "AppIntro" o "Menu", si abres alguna que no cumpla esta condición, se abrirá simplemente desde el inicio.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: voy a probarlo muchas graciasjorge

Comment: Bruno, ahora entiendo, deseas abrir no la Activity que se encuentra definida como launcher, si no cualquiera de la aplicación! @BrunoSosaFastTag

Comment: Exacto Jorge es lo que necesito

Comment: @BrunoSosaFastTag Si comentas que genera la notificación pero no te lleva a la Activity, revisa que valores se obtienen de remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(), ese es el problema.

Comment: como que ese es el problema si me llega todo correcto , pero al clickquear al notificacion , estando cerrada , no realiza ninguna accion , simplemente la abre la app como s la abrieras comunenmente

Comment: @BrunoSosaFastTag Te sugiero agregues tu Manifest.xml para revisar la configuración de las Activities. Al decir que " abre la app como si la abrieras comunenmente ", te refieres a que abre la Activity que esta definida como  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/> pero no llega a abrir Login, AppIntroGalery o TabsActivity ?

Comment: Exactamente Jorge , edito mi pregunto y agrego el manifest

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75458/discussion-between-jorgesys-and-bruno-sosa-fast-tag).

Answer (score 3):

Te comento que si tienes la app cerrada no va a funcionar de esa manera, pues ya lo intente, lo que recomienda la documentación de firebase y que si me funciono, es enviar en la data del mensaje, la activity que busco que se abra al momento de hacerle click a la notificación y claro, el color de fondo para que el icono no se vea todo blanco, yo las envío desde php de esta manera, pero aplicaría para cualquier otra manera de solicitarla:

```
$msg = array(
                'title'        => 'miTitulo',
                'body'         => 'miAsunto',
                'icon'         => 'ic_notifi_icon',
                'sound'        => 'defaultSoundUri',
                'click_action' => 'miActivity',//Actividad que se abrirá al momento de hacer clic en la notificacion
                'color'        => '#3F51B5'
            );

$fields = array(
                    'to'=> '/topics/'.$this->topic, 
                    'notification'  => $msg
                );

$headers = array(
                    'Authorization: key=' . $this->apikey, 
                    'Content-Type: application/json'
                );


$ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
        $result = curl_exec($ch );
        curl_close( $ch );
```

El asunto en cuestión es el **click_action** que es donde indicas que actividad deseas abrir al hacer clic a la notificación. El **color** Sirve para cuando el icono se queda en blanco, pues cuando esta en segundo plano o cerrada, no toma la configuración del listener de firebase.

Esto funciona perfecto cuando la app esta cerrada o en segundo plano.

> [REPOSITORIO](https://gitlab.com/xfxstudios/firebase_form) con formulario php para envío de notificaciones push

Saludos

Comment: Me parece perfecta tu respuesta aunque no sabria como pasar esto a Java ,

Comment: El código java no se toca, pues esta bien como esta ya que te va a funcionar mientra la app esta en primer plano, lo que te coloque es como debes enviar la notificación desde tu servidor hacia tus app, recuerda que si tu app esta cerrada o en segundo plano, las notificaciones las toma el sistema operativo, de alli que se le indique que hacer al hacerle clic

Comment: la verdad no termino de entender y unis lo que me contas , yo mando desde la consola de firebase eso es php?

Comment: donde iria ese codigo que as puesto

Comment: ok dejame decirte que si estas utilizando la consola de firebase para enviar la notificaciones no te va a servir, pues como ellos mismos dicen, esta bastante limitada por ahora, mi recomendación es no utilizar la consola para estos menesteres, es mejor crearse un servidor php para ello, no requiere subirlo a ningun servidor web  incluso funciona en modo local con xamp o laragon por ejemplo. es bastante sencillo de hacer y configurar

Comment: Yo tengo uno que me sirve para enviarle notificaciones a los usuarios de mis apps, y hace poco programe uno para una cliente en argentina que también requería de esa funcionalidad desde su sistema.

Comment: si pudieras habilitarmela me vendria de lujo

Comment: @BrunoSosaFastTag dejame preparar un repo de github y te paso el enlace, esta pendiente

Comment: @BrunoSosaFastTag aqui esta el enlace del formulario: [REPOSITORIO](https://gitlab.com/xfxstudios/firebase_form) es el formulario básico, cualquier cosa me consultas, lo puedes editas a tu antojo. Saludos

Comment: Muchisimas gracias Carlos

Answer (score 2):

Bien una de las formas en hacer lo que tu quieres es obtener los datos desde la actividad principal que es la primera en abrirse.
cuando la app esta cerrada por completo y te llega una notificación al hacer clic en la notificación esta ya te abre el intent principal con datos como Extras, entonces esos extras deberás obtenerlos de la siguiente forma en tu `onResume`

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    if(getIntent().getExtras() != null) {

        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();

        try {
            String actionType = b.getString("action");
            //aquí va tu código en el cual validas el tipo de dato
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Ahora te preguntarás por ejemplo porque mande a obtener `action`, bueno como te pregunte en que si estabas usando la consola de Firebase en al sección **Datos personalizados** puedes poner `action` como la Key y pues lo valores serian los que quieras revisar `Login` `AppIntro` etc.
Esta respuesta va mas a con base mi experiencia al recibir Push notification en FireBase Con la App cerrada y hacer una acción conforme a lo recibido en la notificación.

Como anexo a mi respuesta te envio la liga de como envia los datos al usar FCM: [Recibir Mensajes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive?hl=es-419)

Comment: Dejame probarlo Miguel , muchas gracias

Comment: si claro, me dices si te resulto, saludos

Comment: Hola Miguel, tengo curiosidad de saber ¿porque funcionaría si esta usando FCM que recibe un RemoteMessage y no un Bundle? ¿No estará enviando los datos en realidad mediante FCM :| ? veo que tiene una mezcla ya que define onNewIntent()

Comment: Hola jorge, si claro como dice en la documentacion de Firebase la cual dice que hay dos tipos de cargas de datos en FCM, tanto en primer plano y segundo plano, en primer plano entra directamente a un `onMessageReceived ` y en seguno plano entra a `Bandeja del sistema` la cual esta envia datos en el Intent como Extras

Comment: Tal vez me estoy perdiendo de algo pero onMessageReceived() en primer o segundo plano es el punto donde se generan mis notificaciones en las aplicaciones en las que he trabajado, no importando que este cerrada la aplicación.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive