# ¿como puedo abrir otro activity que no sea el activity principal?

Tags: android, activity

quiero abrir desde una notificacion el acitivity main y otro dependiendo de un parametro pero solo puedo abrir el pricipal y al recibir notificaciones con la app abierta esta se cierra el codigo es el siguiente.

```
private void enviarNotificacion(RemoteMessage.Notification messageBody) {                                                           
    Intent intent;                                                                                                                  
    Notification notificacion;                                                                                                      

    if(messageBody.getClickAction().compareTo(null)==0){                                                                            
        intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);                                                            
    }else{                                                                                                                          
        intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MostrarWeb.class);                                                               
    }                                                                                                                               


    PendingIntent pendingIntent = 
    PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);                                 

    Uri defaultSoundUri= 
    RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);                                          
    notificacion = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)                                                                             
        .setSmallIcon(getResources().getIdentifier(messageBody.getIcon(), 
        "drawable", getApplicationContext().getPackageName()))
        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), 
         R.drawable.ic_noti))                                         
        .setContentTitle(messageBody.getTitle())                                                                                
        .setContentText(messageBody.getBody())                                                                                  
        .setAutoCancel(true)                                                                                                    
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)                                                                                        
        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)                                                                                              
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)                                                                                        
        .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000})                                                                   
        .build();                                                                                                               


    NotificationManager notificationManager =                                                                                       
        (NotificationManager) 
    getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);                           

    notificationManager.notify(0,notificacion);}
```

Comment: Para dar un a respuesta más precisa te sugiero agregues que datos se obtienen en messageBody.

Comment: No abre MostrarWeb.class? que muestra el Logcat?

Comment: El logcat no pone nada simplemente desaparece la notificación y no abre nada, aunque el main si lo abre sabrías decirme como evitar que la App se cierre cuando recibo una notificación?

Answer (score 1):

Tendrías que crear un `Intent` tal que así:

```
Intent nombreIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, MostrarWeb.class);
CurrentActivity.this.startActivity(nombreIntent);
```

Y en el manifest xml ( app > manifests > AndroidManifest.xml ):

```
<activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="MostrarWeb"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Usando `messageBody.getClickAction()` en `onMessageReceived()` siempre retornará un valor null, obtén información de esta forma especificando el nombre del key :

```
messageBody.getData().get(<nombre de key>)
```

pero para esto debes asegurarte que el `payload` en realidad tenga este key y su valor:

```
 'click_action' => 'provengo de la activity ...'
```

Comment: te recomiendo mirar esta pregunta , tiene una respuesta muy buena por parte de @Elenasys https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/151752/notificacion-push-android-hacer-algo-cuando-llega-push-app-cerrada/152626?noredirect=1#comment286291_152626

Comment: lo he cambiado como en el ejemplo es mas estoy usando el mismo codigo php mi pregunta es ¿para abrir n ativity desde la notificacion necesita estar definido como launcher?